# How to split a String by a comma, but from the second comma

Tags: java, android, split

I have a string as:

```
"model=iPhone12,3,os_version=13.6.1,os_update_exist=1,status=1"
```

How can I convert this into:

```
model=iPhone12,3
os_version=13.6.1
os_update_exist=1
status=1
```

Comment: i don't see why it would make a difference that you need to split from the second comma, split from the first one and just use the first two indexes

Answer (score 2):

Split the string from the **first** comma, then re-join the first two elements of the resulting string array.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there's a "clean" way to do this but this would work for your case:

```
String str = "model=iPhone12,3,os_version=13.6.1,os_update_exist=1,status=1";

String[] sp = str.split(",");

sp[0] += "," + sp[1];
sp[1] = sp[2];
sp[2] = sp[3];
sp[3] = sp[4];
sp[4] = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
 public String[] splitString(String source) {

        // Split the source string based on a comma followed by letters and numbers.
        // Basically "model=iPhone12,3,os_version=13.6.1,os_update_exist=1,status=1" will be split
        // like this:
        // model=iPhone12,3
        // ,os_version=13.6.1
        // ,os_update_exist=1
        // ,status=1"
        String[] result = source.split("(?=,[a-z]+\\d*)");

        for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            // Removes the comma at the beginning of the string if present
            if (result[i].matches(",.*")) {
                result[i] = result[i].substring(1);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Actually, it will be like this:

// model=iPhone12
//,3
 // ,os_version=13.6.1
 // ,os_update_exist=1
// ,status=1"

Comment: What will be like that? Have you tried it? I've tested it with your string and I end up with your expected result

Answer (score 0):

if you are parsing always the same kind of String a regex like this will be do the job

```
String str = "model=iPhone12,3,os_version=13.6.1,os_update_exist=1,status=1";
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("model=(.*),os_version=(.*),os_update_exist=(.*),status=(.*)").matcher(str);
    if (m.find()) {
        model = m.group(1)); // iPhone12,3
        os = m.group(2)); // 13.6.1
        update = m.group(3)); // 1
        status = m.group(4)); // 1
    }
```

If you really wants to use a split you can still use that kind of trick

```
String[] split = str.replaceAll(".*?=(.*?)(,[a-z]|$)", "$1#")
    .split("#");
split[0] // iPhone12,3
split[1] // 13.6.1
split[2] // 1
split[3] // 1
```